# jquery-ui set autocomplete width by id of select

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have 4 input  transformed in `autocomplete_combobox`. The code for set width of all `autocomplete_combobox` is this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('width','300px');
```

I want set css width for only one element by knowing Id of `<select>`

How do I do?

---

```
<select name='select1' id='select1' class='combobox'>
<option>element 1</option>
</select>

<select name='select2' id='select2' class='combobox'>
<option>element 2</option>
</select>

<select name='select3' id='select3' class='combobox'>
<option>element 3</option>
</select>

<select name='select4' id='select4' class='combobox'>
<option>element 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: share your html structure, so that we can easily give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing the point, but you can set the width of an element by ID like so:

```
$("#select1").css("width", "300px");
```

Now, if you're doing a combobox like here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox you may need to make this change to the `widget` itself.

```
var myCombo = $("#select1").combobox("widget");
myCombo.find(".ui-autocomplete-input").css("width", "300px");
```

Now all this is a big guess since you didn't provide a complete example, so please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve